# How to get recursively get all leaves of a Tree Structure in Java

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I have a Database Table of a Tree Nodes as below. I want to make a ArrayList in Java out of these Tree Nodes. the Arraylist will recursively fetch all the Tree Nodes in a Recursive Format in Java.

Input:

Database Table

```
Name            ID      Parent_ID
Parent          1   
Child-1         2           1
Child-1.1       3           2
Child-1.1.1     4           3
Child-2         5           1
Child-3         6           1
Child-1.1.1.1   7           4
Child-1.2       8           2
```

I want to make an ArrayList of the above table in the below Java format where Sub is list of the Child Nodes, if no Child Node then Sub is Null.

```
public class Node {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String value;
    private List<Node> sub;
}
```

Output:

1. Parent

   - Child-1

     - Child-1.1

       - Child-1.1.1

         - Child-1.1.1.1
     - Child-1.2
   - Child-2
   - Child-3

Can someone please help in creating a recursive function in Java to implement the above.

Comment: What do you have so far? Can you think of a way to do it iteratively (Would help to come up with a recursive version)?

Comment: What have you done to try and solve this? StackOverflow isn't your 'do my homework' website

Comment: Why exactly is the implementation required to be recursive?

Comment: Hi Codor, 

I am fetching the Database values in two maps: Map1<ID,Name> and Map2<ID,ParentID> . 
From these Two maps, i am trying to create an ArrayList<Node> recursively pushing the elements into it.. 
Something like below:
List mainList = new ArrayList<Node>;
for(Map1<ID,Name>)
{
for(Map2<ID,ParentID>)
{
if(map1.id.equals.map2.parentID)
{
mainList.add(map2.id);  // This will initally add 4 main nodes in the List (Child-1, Child-2, Child-3)
}
}
}
Now Im not sure how to add Child-1.1 to the sub field of Child-1 and that too in recursive manner till n-iteration.
Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved in two steps as follows, where the notation is some Java-ish pseudocode. First, all of the database rows have to be put in a `List<Node> Nodes`, where `Node` should have an additional member `ParentID` and the actual tree structure has to be built. This can be done as follows in time `O(n^2)`, which is not optimal, but makes no additional assumptions on the node indices.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Nodes.Count(); i++) // iterate nodes
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Nodec.Count(); j++) // search parent of i-th node
    {
        if (Nodes[j].id.Equals(Nodes[i].ParentID)) // j-th node is parent of i-th node
        {
            Nodes[j].sub.add(Nodes[i]); // add i-th node to children of j-th node
        }
    }
}
```

Afterwards, the leaves can be identified easily as these are the nodes which have no children.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Nodes.Count(); i++)
{
    if (Nodes[i].sub.Count() == 0) // i-th node is a leaf
    {
        // do something with a leaf
    }
}
```

Note that I am not too familiar with Java from the top of my head, but the algorithmic idea should be understandable.

Comment: Hi Codor, I am fetching the Database values in two maps:

Comment: Hi Codor, 

I am fetching the Database values in two maps: Map1<ID,Name> and Map2<ID,ParentID> . 
From these Two maps, i am trying to create an ArrayList<Node> recursively pushing the elements into it.. 
Something like below:
List mainList = new ArrayList<Node>;
for(Map1<ID,Name>)
{
for(Map2<ID,ParentID>)
{
if(map1.id.equals.map2.parentID)
{
mainList.add(map2.id);  // This will initally add 4 main nodes in the List (Child-1, Child-2, Child-3)
}
}
}
Now Im not sure how to add Child-1.1 to the sub field of Child-1 and that too in recursive manner till n-iteration.
Please guide.

Comment: Hi Codor, Your implementation sounds good .. I will try this. But could you please confirm that if Child-1.1 is added to the sub field of Child-1. if will be removed from the Main Node List. Should I explicitly remove the element from the List after adding it to the sub field of the List

Comment: It is not necessary to remove nodes; nodes are not removed.

Comment: More precisely, the nodes are processed just to represent the child relation in the `sub` member.

Comment: Thank you Codor.. This was useful. Appreciate your efforts :)

Answer (score 1):

Recursive function:

```
public void printTree(Node tree,int num)
{
    if(tree==null || tree.getSub()==null)return;
    for(Node n : tree.getSub())
    {
    System.out.println(new String(new char[num]).replace("\0", "   ")+"*"+n.getName());
printTree(n,num+1);
}
}

public void callRec(Node tree)
{
    System.out.println(tree.getName());
    printTree(tree,1);
}
```

The result will be:

```
Parent
*Child-1
  *Child-1.1
     *Child-1.1.1
        *Child-1.1.1.1
  *Child-1.2
*Child-2
*Child-3
```

Comment: Hi Ben, My list which will be formed is an Arraylist<Node> having sub field containing sub nodes. I am fetching it from the database and forming the Arraylist<Node> as per my above question

Comment: Hi Ben, Initially the sub element will be null for all nodes. We need to fill in the sub elements and make the child nodes based on conditions

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough algo:

```
ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public extract(node root){
    foreach(node i : root.sub)
        extract(i);
    ar.add(i.value);
}
```

Comment: Hi Noel, Initially the sub element will be null for all nodes. We need to fill in the sub elements and make the child nodes based on conditions